# Chanting of mantra

Tags: mantras, siddhi

Normally, a mantra is given by someone who had chanted the mantra and attained the mantra siddhi level. If a mantra "saktipanchakshari" is given, I am told that the mantra needs to be chanted with reference to the chakras in the body. Or, is there any procedure to do sadhana with this mantra? I wish to know if mere chanting and upasana while doing the routine will yield the desired results. Can I request the learned to clarify me in this regard?

Comment: Please meet with a guru in person. They will guide you and course-correct as necessary till you become independent.